# How to add user in Rainloop like admin@domain.com

Tags: centos, vps, rainloop

I was using usermin in my VPS server, but its interface was not up to mark. So, I've installed Rainloop webmail server for one of my domain.

But I am confused about how to add a user to send and receive mail like I used to do with usermin.

Suppose I have a domain called example.com, I want to access a user contact@example.com to rainloop. I want to send and receive mail via contact@example.com.

I can send and receive mail via the same user in usermin, but I don't how to do the same with rainloop.

I am using centOS in my VPS server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

create new user from console, `adduser admin` or `useradd admin`